# Providing lower bound for the support in apriori Algorithm

Tags: database, data-mining, mining

Suppose in a market basket scenario, the following association rules are detected with a support of at least 15% and a confidence of at least 60%:

{A, B} → {C}
{B, C} → {D}

How accurately can you present a lower bound for the support of the itemset {A, B, C, D}?

Can anyone help me understand what is the lower bound I am looking here at in the apriori algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Break this down into two steps. What is the minimum support of ABC?

Then, what is the minimum support of ABCD?

Comment: Oh, but how do I calculate the minimum support of ABC ? Any pointers on what is the minimum support of ABC ?

Comment: See the definition of confidence.